# Using beeline to compile ddl objects from .hql file

Tags: hive

We have couple of hql files for compiling ddls.
in hive we used the following command from bash :

```
hive -v -f abc.hql
```

but, in beeline this doesn't work from bash. Any idea what can be the equivalent command for beeline.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your hiveserver2 is up & running on some port

In beeline

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://localhost:port/database_name/" -f abc.hql
```

Refer this doc for more commands

```
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients
```

Refer this doc if you have not yet configured hiveserver2

```
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2
```